# How can I delete the clicked item from my database... I am new entry for android

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(activity2.this);
            adb.setTitle("Delete?");
            adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + arg0);

            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: do you need help for deleting an entry in db or to know which item is clicked?

Comment: I'm assuming this is part of a ListView. What type of Adapter are you using?

Comment: Where is your code for your db? You need a delete method in there.